# What happens due to & operator in the following case?

Tags: c++, operators

I have known, '&' as bitwise and as an operator to get memory address of a variable.
What happens in this case of the code?
res = res & (a[i]<[a[i+1]]);

If it is bitwise and , as far as I know the second condition is also checked,
but what if I used logical and instead of it , wouldn't it still be the same?

As first part is (say) false , second parts get checked comes true, but still res remains false.

Would it be same (for this case) to use logical and for this? or it has some other use (& operator) for this case?

```
int a[] {1,3,4,2};
int pos = 3;
bool res = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        res &= (a[i] < a[i + 1]);
```

(Sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If it is bitwise and , as far as I know the second condition is also checked, but what if I used logical and instead of it , wouldn't it still be the same?

No. Boolean and (written as `&&` or `and`) has short circuit evaluation - if left part is false right part is not evaluated at all. This allows to write code like this:

```
if( pointer != nullptr && pointer->value > 100 ) ...
```

if not short circuit evaluation this code would have UB. For example this code:

```
if( pointer != nullptr & pointer->value > 100 ) ...
```

has Undefined Behaviour when `pointer` is equal to `nullptr`

> Would it be same (for this case) to use logical and for this? or it has some other use (& operator) for this case?

You cannot, as there is no `&&=` operator in C++. You can write:

```
res = res && (a[i] < a[i + 1]);
```

and that would have short circuit as well and compiler may even be smart enough to stop the loop, though I doubt and it should be expressed explicitly anyway:

```
bool res = true;
for(int i = 0; res && i < pos; i++)
    res = a[i] < a[i + 1];
```

which does the same, but cleaner and more efficient.

Anyway when you need logical or boolean and you should use one to make your intention clear and avoid unexpected surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the short circuiting issue, If `res == 2` then:

`res & 1` will return `0` which will be interpreted as `false`.

`res && 1` will return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. 
Okay, let's dive into your code.

Your given code is very clear. You are performing bitwise and for pos(3) times. For every loop you are comparing a[i] with a[i+1]. Please note that for the last loop, I mean when variable i becomes 3, then i+1 will be 4. And your array a[] doesn't have a[4]. It only has the last element having index 3.

So for bitwise and operation the value of res isn't predictable as a[4] isn't defined.

Now let's think about logical AND operation. For logical and your expression inside the for loop will once generate a false boolean value for a[i] < a[i+1] as your array a[] = {1,3,4,2}. Here 4>2 not 4<2. Hence it will generate false boolean value and your entire response will be false 'cause you know logical AND will be eventually 0 if one of the operands is false.

I think you have got this.

Comment: i < pos(3) , so max value i(variable) will reach is 2?  and 2+1 = 3 , i don't think this shall reach index[4]